# send mail in android application without smtp.gmail.com

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I should send email trough app but I want send it from another mail account (no gmail). I've coded a class Mail and I set host="mail@xxxxxx.xx" but in debug mode I've seen that variable host is = "smtp.gmail.com". How is possible? There is a trick?

Comment: I think you can get the answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a

Comment: no, this post is irrelevant for my problem

Answer (score 0):

You're using the JavaMail API to send the mail, right?

Check the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html), there's several ways to specify the host you want to connect to, including setting a property or passing it explicitly in the call to the connect method.  Without more detail on what exactly you're doing, it's hard to say where you went wrong.